# How do I result in a Float number with 2 integers?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, int

```
var ratings = 3193;
var reviews = 9;

var average = parseFloat(ratings) / reviews;  //I want a floating point number at the end.
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Couldn't you simply try this?

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion isn't necessary. JavaScript automatically converts between types. And numbers are not actually represented as integers internally. They're all floating point anyway.

So, the simplest solution should have the desired effect:

```
var ratings = 3193;
var reviews = 9;
var average = ratings/reviews;
```

What you have in your example causes the engine to convert `ratings` to a String and parse that string as a double (theoretically resulting in the value it had to begin with) before treating it as the numerator in your calculation.

Comment: It may be of interest, however, that the [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) internally convert their operands to signed 32-bit integers. So, `(ratings/reviews) | 123 == 354.77 | 123 == 354 | 123`.

Answer (score 2):

All numbers in JavaScript are double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754. There is no need to typecast "integers" into "floats" as you would expect it from C/C++ and other languages. You need `parse*` only if you handle strings.

See also:

- [Number value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19)

> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value
>
> [`parseInt`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2), [`parseFloat`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.3) (both take a string as parameter)